# Android:Including content description in styles xml file

Tags: android, android-xml

After beginning to use the Android Lint tool in Eclipse I'm getting many new warnings. One of them is saying that my ImageViews are missing a contentDescription.

For regular ImageViews I do it like this, and it works just fine:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
    ....
</ImageView>
```

However, if I have an ImageView that's using a style xml file, like this:

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
    android:src="@drawable/title_logo" />
```

and if I in my styles.xml have this:

```
<style name="TitleBarLogo">
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/imgViewDesc</item>
    ....
</style>
```

the warning does *not* go away.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

See http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

I think you are circumventing the purpose of contentDescription by putting it in a style. contentDescription is to identify the image for accessibility. By deferring it into the style, you are losing the inference that this contentDescription describes this particular image.